# Why did the second TextView in Horizontal LinearLayout not align to it's top?

Tags: android

I had the xml as shown below, but dit why the second TextView not align to the top of the LinearLayout?

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:text="AAAA"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="9dp"
        android:text="BBBB"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and the result is

[image]

The TextView with id "tv_2" did not align to the LinearLayout and seems like had several pixes space, I'll be very appreciate that anyone can tell me the reason.

Comment: You'll need to set `android:baselineAligned="false"` on the `<LinearLayout>`. By default, a horizontal `LinearLayout` will align the baselines of the first line of text in each `TextView` child. In your case, the second, shorter `TextView` is being shifted down, so its baseline lines up with the first's.

Comment: I tried it and it did work.Thank you very much!!